# Is there a defined way to update preact app that was created with preact-cli?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I'm looking into preact and tools around it for a limited functionality app that should go to production in a few weeks.

My concern is future maintenance: if I create my app from a template with preact-cli, is there an easy way to update my app with latest upgrades and config changes after some time when the template upgrades?

I'm looking for a doc page similar to create-react-app's update notes https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automated way to apply new changes, assuming this is what you're looking for — even `create-react-app` doesn't have that. Quoting this paragraph from the doc page:

> To update an existing project to a new version of `react-scripts`, open the changelog, find the version you’re currently on (check `package.json` in this folder if you’re not sure), and apply the migration instructions for the newer versions.

Preact also offers migration guides. Once your project has been scaffolded, there's no easy way to grab the latest updates, but you can follow their docs (example upgrading from v8):

https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/upgrade-guide/

If you ever find yourself wanting to get those upgrades, one way to do that could be generating a new, separate project, and applying those changes manually; going through their guide might still be the best way.